# Laravel query select rows till column sum < x

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Looking for a query to select rows till the sum of a specific column reach a value, i tried

```
    $type = Table::select("*",
                    DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(to_qt) FROM ordens
                                WHERE type = ".$request->type."
                                'soma')"))
            ->having('soma', '2')
            ->get();
```

but obviously it is very wrong, i've searched a lot and found postgree solutions, but i'm not an expert on queries and i was not able to adapt this to laravel, all i know is that apparently i need to do a select inside another select, anyone know how can i do this?

Comment: you could do DB::raw and write a mysql function or procedure for that and then access that

Answer (score 1):

You Can try this.

```
$type = DB::raw("SELECT SUM(to_qt) as to_qt_sum, column1, column2, column3  FROM ordens WHERE type = ".$request->type." having SUM(to_qt) = 2 group by column1, column2, column3")->get();
```

add you column name in select and group by.

If you are using model, then you can go with this below method also

```
$type = Orden::selectRaw('SUM(to_qt) as to_qt_sum, column1, column2, column3')
        ->groupBy('column1', 'column2', 'column3')->having('to_qt', 2)
        ->get();
```

Comment: if my answer is satisfied, please mark it. Thanks you for your vote.